v-if in a nested v-for is rendering in development but not in production
v-if in a nested v-for is rendering in development but not in production. I recently deployed to a shared host and the conditional v-if is not rendering. Initially I used v-show and that did not help.
<tr v-for="student in students" v-bind:key="student.id"
    class="bg-white border dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white">
    <th scope="row" class="border-blue-700 border pl-3 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
        {{ student.first_name }} {{ student.last_name }}
    </th>
    <td v-for="exercise in exercises" v-bind:key="exercise.id" class="border-blue-700 text-center border">
        <div v-for="mark in exercise.marks" v-bind:key="mark.id" class="text-black dark:text-white">
            <span v-show="mark.student_id === student.id">{{ mark.score }}</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

I first used v-show and that did not help. I later used v-if and the problem persists, not rendering in production.

Do you have any relevant errors in the console?

I changed the conditional from identity check to equality check and everything is now functioning, both local and production. No errors in the console or warnings.  Instead of v-show="mark.student_id === student.id", i changed to v-show="mark.student_id == student.id"
